# What does @enablesns @enablesqs annotations do (spring cloud aws)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-aws

I have been trying to find documentation of @enablesns @enablesqs annotations but can't find them.

They seem to be required for the sqs and sns integration to work.
But I'd just like to have a better understanding, and be sure I'm not using them wrong.

Any description would be of great help.

Comment: Maybe a look in the [configuration tests](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/tree/master/spring-cloud-aws-messaging/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/config/annotation) might help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/blob/master/spring-cloud-aws-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/config/annotation/EnableSns.java) for those two annotations:

```
@Import({SnsConfiguration.class, SnsWebConfiguration.class})
public @interface EnableSns
```

Where `@Import` [does the following](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Import.html):

> @interface Import:
>   Indicates one or more @Configuration classes to import.

Long story short: Those annotations only combine multiple `@Configuration` classes into one single annotation.

E.g. `@EnableSns` does the same as adding `@SnsConfiguration` and `@SnsWebConfiguration` which provide you with `AmazonSNS`, `RegionProvider` and `AWSCredentialsProvider` beans.